# Why I can use private methods from template functions

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

I have template class MyClass

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass() { }
private:
  void PrivateFunction() { 
    std::cout << "Message From Private Function" << std::endl; 
  }
};
```

Now when I am trying to use PrivateFunction() inside another function compiler reports error, but when I am trying the same inside template function compiler doesn't show any error.

1. Compiler doesn't report error.

   ```
   template <class T>
   void f()
   {
     MyClass<int> a;
     a.PrivateFunction();
   }
   ```
2. Compiler reports error.

   ```
   void f()
   {
     MyClass<int> a;
     a.PrivateFunction();
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you called template function `f()` yet?

Comment: Yes only in that case I get the error, but I am interested why I cant see error before calling the function.

Comment: Whether you get an error depends on the compiler. clang shows an error for both 1 and 2, even if `f` is never instantiated.

Comment: No valid instantiation can be generated for the template `f()` in 1, so the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Whether the compiler diagnose the error at template definition time or instantiation time is a quality-of-implementation issue.

Comment: Here is a cool video series where Mr. STL tells how those (and many other) things work: [Core C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-). If you are beginning your [tag:language-lawyer] career, it's worth to take a look!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *Why I can use private methods from template functions?*

You can't. §14.6 [temp.res]/p4:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

---

> *I am interested why I cant see error before calling the function*

A compiler may defer the analysis until the function template is instantiated. Still, this is an implementation-defined behavior, and your code remains *ill-formed* (the continuation of §14.6/p4):

> [ *Note*: If a template is instantiated, errors will be diagnosed according to the other rules in this Standard. **Exactly when these errors are diagnosed is a quality of implementation issue**. — *end note* ]

[GCC demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25f1d59d15afbd23) (issues an error only on instantiation)
[Clang demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/764635c6a3306432) (issues an error without instantiation)

Comment: This isn't very accurate. The template is ill-formed with no diagnostic required, so the compiler is free to diagnose it if it wants to. Whether it does so is a quality of implementation issue, and at least one compiler (Clang) does diagnose the error without requiring instantiation of `f()`.

Comment: Being pedantic helps here: There is no such thing as a template function. There are function templates which can be used to generate functions. If a function template generates an ill-formed function that specific function gets reported with an error. Telling if a function template can only generate ill-formed functions is more difficult and it is debatable if that is even an error.

Comment: This diagnostic isn't required because it would be too hard to specify which problems are sufficiently obvious that they could be diagnosed without instantiation. E.g. `private` methods can be called by friends, which means you need to figure out  - without actual instantiation - whether a function template instantiation would be a friend.